# Разбор строки с помощью регулярных выражений Javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

```
                 значение элемента   элемент    элемент  Значение элемента
 Массив          lat в массиве NV    массива    массива  CSQ5 в массиве NV
    |                    |            |             |    |
    NV:111203 034940:42.6699:42.6988:CSQ1:434.....CSQ5:1023
             |                  |         |
значение элемента      значение элемента  Значение элемента    
datetime в массиве NV  lon в массиве NV   CSQ1 в массиве NV
```

В итоге должно получиться:

```
var nv = {
          "datetime":["111203 034940"],
          "lat": [42.6699],
          "lon": [42.6988],
          "CSQ1": [434],
          ................,
          ................,
          "CSQ5": [1023] 

}
```

Как это сделать с помщью регулярного выражения?

Comment: Тут не нужны регулярные выражения, делите строку по двоеточиям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем, говорите, вам регулярное выражение?

Можно же использовать `String.prototype.split`, а потом работать с отдельными кусками строки, например, так:

```
var parse = function(str) {
    var res = {};

    var data = str.split(':').reverse(),
        name = data.pop();

    res[name] = {};
    res[name].datetime = data.pop();
    res[name].lat = data.pop();
    res[name].lon = data.pop();

    data = data.reverse();
    for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i += 2) {
        res[name][data[i]] = data[i+1];
    }

    return res;
}

var s = 'NV:111203 034940:42.6699:42.6988:CSQ1:434:CSQ5:1023';
console.dir(parse(s));
```

Comment: Регулярные выражения же :) `var data = str.split( /:/ ).reverse()`

Comment: @ReinRaus, что-то мне подсказывает, что `str.split(':')` будет работать быстрее :)

Comment: http://jsperf.com/split-regex-vs-string

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогли!!! Нужно развивать логику...